# Microsoft Visual Studio Developer command prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-7, visual-studio-2019

After installing Microsoft Visual Studio community 2019 and choosing game development on installer, as well as microsoft visual studio code, i open the developer command prompt and there's an error already there. 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Then typing cl, i get the same error.

Comment: Have uninstalled and reinstalled everything about 4 times.

Comment: Something i tried is to use echo %path% and it came back starting with mingw

Comment: might just need to set the correct path but am unsure how to do this